# Squish 3 images together horizontally

Tags: graphics, floats, white-space

I have three graphs together on a page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, left=2cm, top = 1.7cm, bottom=1.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear, super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]

    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{"../../Graphs for Jan/graph_left"}
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{"../../Graphs for Jan/graph_middle"}
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{"../../Graphs for Jan/graph_right"}

    \caption[Fit for different redshift ranges]{The best fits for each redshift range, $ (U-K)/(W2-NUV) $ for $ z<1 $ (left), $ (I-W2)/(W3-U) $ for $ 1<z<3 $ (middle) and $ (I-SPIT8)/(W4-R) $ for $ z>3 $ (right).}
    \label{fig:3graphs}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I'd like them to have as little whitespace between them as possible, and to go outside the margins if necessary. I don't need them as subfigures, they function as one graph (i.e. the red one goes from `0<x<1`, green from `1<x<3`, blue from `3<x`. How can I get them closer together?

Comment: 1) If the images are PDFs, then `pdfcrop` might be a very useful tool. 2) Use `0.333` and not `0.32` of `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your used images to `example-image-a` etc. from package `mwe` which must be installed, but not called ...

Now please see the following corrected and shortend mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, left=2cm, top = 1.7cm, bottom=1.7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering%
  \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
  \caption[Fit for different redshift ranges]{The 
    best fits for each redshift range, $ (U-K)/(W2-NUV) 
    $ for $ z<1 $ (left), $ (I-W2)/(W3-U) $ for $ 1<z<3 $ (middle) and 
    $ (I-SPIT8)/(W4-R) $ for $ z>3 $ (right).}
  \label{fig:3graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I added `%` after your images and used `.33` instead your `.32` because the added `%` deletes the space between the images ... as you can see in the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

I suggest not to expand the graphics into margins and in your case it seems not to be needed ...

Answer (score 0):

If you trim as much whitespace as you dare from each image (keeping all a similar width), then it is easy to push them into the margins without affecting other settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, left=2cm, top = 1.7cm, bottom=1.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear, super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]

    \centering

    \parbox{1.1\textwidth}{\hspace{-1.0cm}\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

    \caption[Fit for different redshift ranges]{The best fits for each redshift range, $ (U-K)/(W2-NUV) $ for $ z<1 $ (left), $ (I-W2)/(W3-U) $ for $ 1<z<3 $ (middle) and $ (I-SPIT8)/(W4-R) $ for $ z>3 $ (right).}
    \label{fig:3graphs}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```